# Remove laravel 5 and install laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, composer-php

I was about to install laravel 4 but accidentally installed laravel 5 instead, now I need to remove 5 and install 4, I tried to change in the composer the line that says: require: "laravel/framework": "5.1.*", and overwrite it by "laravel/framework": "4.2.*", but when I create a new project it still creates it in laravel 5 unless I point to version 4 with the creation command, any help?

Comment: Any special reason not to delete what you just made and start from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

Go into your composer.json folder, and edit

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*" << change this to 4.2
    "torann/laravel-asana": "0.2.*@dev",
    "asana/asana": "^0.1.2"
},
```

then run `composer dump-autoload` and then try to run `composer update`.

Comment: @SamJoni found a lengthy disscussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/2vzxqd/downgrade_to_42/

Answer (score 0):

when you use the composer command you can specify which version you want to install you can do that like :

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=4.2 yourdirectoryname
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

there... I also faced a similar problem when trying to do my mini project. In order to clear the old Laravel application installed Just delete the laravel. bat as shown in my screenshot. You also need to clear the cache memory 
like

> php artisan cache:clear

This will get rid of the laravel and your system is ready for a fresh installation.